# python, how map a data frame with input value with 2 conditional statement

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need make an id attribution for fields that are empty, but I have to use id's from the some class to execute this properly.

With the code bellow, I was able to accomplished that.

#### but there are some issues

- 1- I have multiple "vendorname" so have to do it for all of them
- 2- Into every "vendorname" there is 3 diferent classes, low medium, core
- 3 -I dont now how to get all this campaignid, combined with the original Dataframe in the end.

```
cw:

 lead_date  vendorname  captureurl      campaignid
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_HAS        0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    Nan
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Bagde      Nan
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    Nan
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      0000000002
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      Nan
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      Nan
2019-10-01       Google     rt:Low_Generic      0000000003
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    0000000004
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    Nan
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    0000000005
```

#### My Approach:

- I grabbed all records contains 'google'
- Then grabbed all contains 'Core'
- Then give a id that correspond to that record

```
# for Core at google

google = cw[cw.vendorname.str.contains('Google')]

x = google[google.captureurl.str.contains('Core')]

x.campaignid = x.campaignid.fillna("0000000001")
```

#### Expected output

```
 lead_date  vendorname  captureurl      campaignid
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_HAS        0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Bagde      0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Lib_Core_Generic    0000000001
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      0000000002
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      0000000002
2019-10-01       Google     Medium_Generic      0000000002
2019-10-01       Google     rt:Low_Generic      0000000003
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    0000000004
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    0000000005
2019-10-01      Facebook    Lib_Core_Generic    0000000005
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @ansev refresh the question

Comment: thanks!, please check my answer:)

Comment: @ansev 
Works!!! I change the code for "bfill" and it just worked.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on Google and Facebook [`bffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

```
#df.campaignid=df.campaignid.replace('Nan',np.nan)
df= ( df.groupby('vendorname',sort=False) 
     .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().where(x['vendorname'].str.contains('Google'),x.bfill()))
    )
print(df)
```

---

```
     lead_date vendorname        captureurl  campaignid
0   2019-10-01     Google      Lib_Core_HAS  0000000001
1   2019-10-01     Google  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000001
2   2019-10-01     Google    Lib_Core_Bagde  0000000001
3   2019-10-01     Google  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000001
4   2019-10-01     Google  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000001
5   2019-10-01     Google    Medium_Generic  0000000002
6   2019-10-01     Google    Medium_Generic  0000000002
7   2019-10-01     Google    Medium_Generic  0000000002
8   2019-10-01     Google    rt:Low_Generic  0000000003
9   2019-10-01   Facebook  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000004
10  2019-10-01   Facebook  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000005
11  2019-10-01   Facebook  Lib_Core_Generic  0000000005
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, so I didnt get error  running the code, but nothing changed. there are still the Nan values for campaignid.

Comment: NaN are string? 
you may need to uncomment the line of my code

Comment: I uncommented and still not working, do you have any suggestion like. what can I change at the parameters ?

Comment: Is the lead_data column of your original data frame like the one you have shown?

Comment: isnt Im sorry, it's a timestamp I belive, like this = 2019-10-01 00:20:37

Comment: There is the fault, because in my code it is also grouped by this column ... so all you need is to remove this groupby tag. I just updated the solution

Comment: Tell me if now works, solution updated! Now only groupby  by 'vendorname': `df.groupby('vendorname',sort=False) `

Comment: thank you again for replying, so still doesnt work and no errors, the code runs just fine. but nothing is happening with NaN values, it still there for Google

Comment: This surely happens because you will have a group full of NaN Values. Try to understand how groupby ffill and bffill works. Also you can try after apply `df.campagined = df.campagined.ffill() `or `df.campagined = df.campagined.bffill()`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

google = cw[cw['vendorname']=='Google']

x = google[google['captureurl'].str.contains('Core')]
x['campaignid'].fillna('0000000001', inplace = True)
```

Comment: thanks for helping @Sadrach, this works just for one vendor.
the challenge is.. there are many vendors

so I will have to copy/paste and modify this line of codes like 20 times.

It will be a big junk of code, also need to have alll this id in the original dataframe